# Trouble with animation(Blendspace1D or blendspace2D)

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

i have an issue in blendspace1D and blendspace2D (using animation tree and animation node state machine whenever i use blendspace2d to animate my character movement to left or right. unfortunately the left(walk)animation gets prioritized even if i press the right(move) key

---

```
extends CharacterBody2D


@export var MAX_SPEED = 300
@export var ACCELERATION = 1500
@export var FRICTION = 1300
@onready var axis = Vector2.ZERO
@onready var animation_tree = get_node("AnimationPlayer/AnimationTree")
@onready var animation_node = animation_tree.get("parameters/playback")

func _physics_process(delta):
    move(delta)

func get_input_axis():
    axis.x = int(Input.is_action_pressed("right")) - int(Input.is_action_pressed("left"))
    axis.y = int(Input.is_action_pressed("down")) - int(Input.is_action_pressed("up"))
    return axis.normalized()

func move(delta):
    
    axis = get_input_axis()
    
    if axis == Vector2.ZERO:
        apply_friction(FRICTION * delta)
        animation_node.travel("Idle")
    else:
        apply_movement(axis * ACCELERATION * delta)
        animation_node.travel("walk")

    move_and_slide()

func apply_friction(amount):
    if velocity.length() > amount:
        velocity -= velocity.normalized() * amount
    else:
        velocity = Vector2.ZERO
        
        
func apply_movement(accel):
    velocity += accel
    velocity = velocity.limit_length(MAX_SPEED)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BlendSpace1D` and `BlendSpace2D` pick an animation based on a parameter called `"blend_position"`.

For `BlendSpace1D` the `"blend_position"` parameter will be an input `float`. And for `BlendSpace2D` it will be an input `Vector2`.

Using the parameter they pick an animation based on the direction of motion or the direction the player character is looking at. *For example, you can "idle_up", "idle_down", "idle_left", and "idle_right" animations, and use `BlendSpace2D` to pick one in runtime based on a direction vector.*

---

You need to set the `"blend_position"` like this:

```
animation_tree.set("parameters/NameOfTheBlendSpàce/blend_position", value)
```

Where:

- `"NameOfTheBlendSpàce"` is the name of the BlendSpace you want to set.
- `value` is the input `float` or `Vector2D` depending if it is is a 1D or 2D BlendSpace respectively.